# Highcharts highstock update date filter with javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to manually update highstock date filter using js. I have tried updating the inputs but that doesn't seem to really work, so I wonder if it is even possible.
[image: highstock filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That inputs are directly connected to the first xAxis on the chart. In other words, to update them (and also actual range on the chart) use [`chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes).

Note: `min` and `max` values have to be timstamps.